# Rails 3.1: alias /images to /assets directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I'm upgrading to rails 3.1 and I need to have the /images directory be an alias to /assets. Is this possible? The reason being I don't want emails that I have sent out to clients which have direct links to files in /images to break.

Is this possible at the web server level? I'm on nginx.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this in nginx

```
location /images {
    alias /usr/share/rails_app/public/assets/images;
}
```

Though I think the bigger problem will be when you run

```
rake assets:precompile
```

It will add a md5hash string to your images.  This hash string is added to force browsers to download changed images, so it doesn't use the browser cache.  Since the names of the images will be different.  It might make more sense to host the old images in a static directory with nginx.

Comment: To fix the MD5 problem, you can remove the hash generation when compiling the assets (in the production.rb file)... it's not "recommended", but it's possible...

Comment: With Rails 3.1.1 the precompile task generates files with and without MD5s for just this use-case. Set far future headers in the assets folder, but not the images folder.